# how can I make federated storage engine connection in oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I'm currently switching my project database from mySQL to oracle, and I'm new to oracle.

Previously, mySQL Query looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE log_remote (
    log_no NUMBER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dttm DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
    log_code VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    log_type VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    product VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    detail VARCHAR2(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    hmac VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL',
    PRIMARY KEY (log_no, dttm)
    ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=FEDERATED
    CONNECTION='mysql://dblink:project!dblink@${Ip}:3306/cli/cli_log'
```

Problem is, I don't know how to make this query

```
CONNECTION='mysql://dblink:project!dblink@${Ip}:3306/cli/cli_log'
```

in oracle SQL. I heard that I can't use federated storage engine connection in oracle
but I can't find how to make the equivalent query in oracle.

Can someone help me out? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know MySQL so I Googled. It says that

> The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database ...

If that's so, in Oracle you'd use a **database link**. Then access table(s) - which reside in another database - over the database link.

Here's an example. User - which creates the database link - has to have that privilege which means that privileged user (such as SYS, who owns the database) has to grant it:

```
SQL> grant create database link to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

`scott` user will then create the DB link to user `hr`:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create database link dbl_hr
  2  connect to hr
  3  identified by hr
  4  using 'xe';

Database link created.
```

Does it work?

```
SQL> select * from dual@dbl_hr;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

Yes, it works.